# Python3 \t is printed in text instead of actually doing tab

Tags: python, python-3.x, configparser

I've been trying to get a Python 3 script be able to write intention from a config with settings using multi lines. Instead of printing the indent it instead print everything in plane text.

```
[DEFAULT]
FooParam = 
    Line1
    \tLine2
    \tLine3
    Line4
```

Above example return the following output both as `print (FooParam)` and as `f.writelines (FooParam)`:

```
Line1
\tLine2
\tLine3
Line4
```

I've also tried to make additional spaces and this did not work either.

```
[DEFAULT]
FooParam = 
    Line1
        Line2
        Line3
    Line4
```

with the same output;

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
Line4
```

The string I use to call the target parameter look like this:

`FooParam = cfg.get(make_target, "FooParam", fallback="")`

Is there are a way to make tabs being taken in consideration when reading from a config?

Comment: Can you post a small concise code which one can use to reproduce the issue? Hard to debug given the current code

Comment: The text content is parsed from the INI file literally, so a `\t` has no special meaning there and will be represented as text. Also, the config parser ignores leading and trailing whitespace in text values. – The solution would probably be to either write your own parser, or use a different better-suited file format.